# SSIS debuging tool in SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I want to trace the execution and see the changes in variables in the package during the runtime. the Microsoft report tool for the SSIS package is not sufficient. I want more details and don't have access to its code in the visual studio.
Is there a plugin for reporting or debugging for SSIS packages in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have sufficient access to SSISDB, which it sounds like you do if you are wanting to hook debugging tools up to it, you should be able to export the packages and open them in VS from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481758/how-to-download-ssis-packages-from-ssisdb amongst other resources (search “export from SSISDB”).

Depending on protection levels some configuration information will not be exported, but that will likely be connection strings and other credentials that you'll need to change in a test environment anyway (or, again assuming you have sufficient privilege, you will be able to find out by other means).

There is no way that I am aware of to debug directly against packages published in SSISDB.